# Low air flow from air conditioner vent

Tags: ac, kia, soul

2012 Kia Soul air conditioning blows weak but cold air and doesn't
do well in hot weather.

Thanks

Comment: When you change the fan speed settings, does it change the speed of the fan at all? Does the fan sound like it's running hard (as it usually should) but the air isn't blowing? Does it seem to blow harder when the car is moving (assuming you don't have it on recirculate)?

Comment: Fan speed changes but seems to make more effort but still not much volume

Answer (score 1):

Checked the air cabin filter and found it needed to be replaced. Honestly didn't think it would affect the air flow inside as it did.

Always start with the simple things.

Comment: Anything that restricts the plenum air flow across the evaporator core (the cold part of the AC) will affect the thermal efficiency , Changing the filter advice applies to both automotive AC as well as your heat pump in the home .

Comment: Thanks...always considered the cabin filter to be more cosmetic...had to remove the glove box to change it